# if statement use inside getline() function in C

Tags: c, if-statement

This is a program to print the longest line from *The C Programming Language* book by K&R.

My doubt is what is the necessity of the code.

```c
    if(c == '\n'){
     s[i]=c;
     ++i;
    }
```

in the `getLine()` function.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
# define MAXLINE 1000  /*maximum length of the input line*/

int getLine(char s[],int line);
void copy(char from[],char to[]);

int main(){
    int curr_len; //current line length
    int max_len = 0;  // maximum line length so far

    char curr_line[MAXLINE];             // Current input line
    char longest_line[MAXLINE];     // maximum line saved so far

    while((curr_len = getLine(curr_line,MAXLINE))>0){
        if(curr_len>max_len){
            copy(curr_line,longest_line);  //save the longest line
            max_len = curr_len;
        }
    }
    if(max_len>0){
        printf("%s\n",longest_line);
    }
    return 0;

}

/* getline: read a line into s, return length*/
int getLine(char s[],int maxline){
    int c,i;
    for(i=0;i<maxline-1 && (c = getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';++i){
        s[i]=c;
        if(c == '\n'){
            s[i]=c;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    s[i]='\0';
    return  i;
}

/* copy: copy 'from' into 'to'; assume to is big enough */
void copy(char from[],char to[]){
    int i=0;
    while((to[i] = from[i])!='\0'){
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Please explain why the if statement is used inside the `getLine()` function.

Comment: looks like an error

Comment: @SOHAN D P It seems you incorrectly copied the function. As far as I know in the original function the if statement is placed outside the for loop.:)

Answer (score 4):

> my doubt is what is the necessity of the code.

Yes it is useless code.

Given, `c == '\n'` in never true.

```
    for(i=0;i<maxline-1 && (c = getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';++i){
        s[i]=c;
        if(c == '\n'){
```

---

The code is not accurately copied from "*The C programming Language* book by K&R" (page 29, 2nd edition).

It looks like a refactoring error from the book — the OP added `{}` incorrectly.

```
// More like K & R
int getLine(char s[],int lim){
    int c, i;
    for(i=0; i<lim-1 && (c = getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n';++i) // no bracket here
        s[i]=c;
    // This if is not part of the loop.
    if (c == '\n'){
       s[i]=c; // Also save the '\n`.
       ++i;
    }
    s[i]='\0';
    return  i;
}
```

K&R code makes sense - even it it have other problems like `lim <= 1`, not best handing of input error, ...

Comment: @SOHANDP Yes, properly transcribed code handles the `'\n'` with `if (c == '\n'){ s[i]=c; ++i; }`.

Comment: now i understood, if (c == '\n') { s[i]=c; ++i; } is outside the for loop.

Comment: Now, if you were suggesting `c = 0;` to accommodate the case where `lim` is 0 or 1, so `c` is not assigned in the loop condition, so you are referencing an uninitialized `c` after the loop …  And the code would certainly benefit from ensuring that `lim` is not zero or negative.  And another point to note is that POSIX has a `getline()` function with a very different signature and set of semantics — that name is no longer a good one to use on POSIX-ish systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, `c==0` helps when `lim == 1`.  The overall design of `getline_like()` functions is wrought with corner cases, often not well handled.